# Set button title to bean message in a JSP

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

I have a JSP question for you that I've been googling...
I am using a title tag to display a long sentence on hover. However I want to put the sentence in a bean message and therefore set the title property equal to a bean message for example:
Define message in struts-resources as…. My.hover_description = “blah blah blah and more blah”

JSP code:

```
<TD>
<html:button title= "<bean:message key=" My.hover_description "/> "
</html:button>
</TD>
```

I also tried but I think  it’s just taking my quote as literal text rather than code:

```
<TD>
<html:button title= '<bean:message key=" My.hover_description "/>'
</html:button>
</TD>
```

So I’m wondering if I have to escape the quotes like so /” /” at the beginning and end of title definition or is there another way to escape the characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TD>
<input type="button" title='<bean:messagekey="My.hover_description"/>'
class="myClass" value='My Button'>
</TD>
```

This is the easy way...

Comment: This doesn't works. Content of title is interpreted as string literal

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a JSP tag to declare the value of an attribute on another JSP tag because it doesn't execute the tag in the attribute declaration first. You can use a JSP tag to declare the value of an attribute on a standard HTML tag because the JSP tag is executed by the server, but the HTML isn't interpreted until it reaches the browser (i.e. there's no conflict in execution order).

You'll need to store the text into a variable first, then use it, something like this:

```
<c:set var="buttonTitle"><bean:message key="My.hover_description"/></c:set>
<html:button title="${buttonTitle}"...>...</html:button>
```

Comment: Ok I understand what you are saying and it makes sense. My JSP is just complaining about the <c:set var="buttonTitel"> tag saying it unknown tag which casuses the same issue I had with the sing quotes above. Did you just use that <c: as an example or can that actually be used?

Comment: @user2218297 It's part of the [JSTL core](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) tag library. Seems like you don't have that available in your project or, if you do, it's not available in your JSP because you don't have the taglib directive there to make it available for use.